# Проблема со стилями CSS. Определенный стиль <img src>

Tags: javascript, php, css

Всем привет,есть проблема,делаю чат,и имеется такой CSS

```
    #frame .content .messages ul li img {
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Данный код действует на этот **div**

```
  <li class="sent">
                    <img src="<?php echo $messages['ava'];?>" class="online" alt="" />
                    <p>Имя: <?php echo $messages['name'];?></br><?php echo $messages['message'];?></br></br>› <?php echo date('j.m.Y в H:i:s', $messages['time']);?></p>
                </li>
```

Суть проблемы:
Если я в чат отправляю картинку,она наследует стиль,как этого избежать?
Ибо этот код делает аватарки нужного размера и в нужном месте,но абсолютно портит вывод изображений в чате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это выглядит.В браузере в отладке так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу убрать наследование стиля для текста сообщения?

Comment: `>`............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не добавить просто к картинке класс и обращаться к нему?

Во-первых: парсинг таких конструкций `#frame .content .messages ul li img` сложен для браузера. Лучше так не делать
Во-вторых: так сложнее понимать, что происходит. Не очень масштабируется, так как стили привязаны жестко к верстке

```
<li class="sent">
  <img src="<?php echo $messages['ava'];?>" class="avatar online" alt="" />
  <p>
    Имя: <?php echo $messages['name'];?></br><?php echo $messages['message'];?>
    </br></br>› <?php echo date('j.m.Y в H:i:s', $messages['time']);?>
  </p>
</li>


#frame .content .messages .avatar {
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Вроде заработало так,спасибо.Отмечу как верный,когда сайт даст разрешение,пишет что еще 7 минут)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант при помощи селектора `>`:

```css
.message > img {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <img class="msg-img" alt="Изображение со стилем">
  <p><img alt="Изображение без стиля"></p>
</div>
```